# Virtual network was not found

Tags: azure, terraform, databricks, azure-virtual-network

I am trying to setup a databricks into subet and protect it by firewalls using the following code in Terraform:

Setup resource group:

```
provider "azurerm" {

  features {
    resource_group {
      prevent_deletion_if_contains_resources = false
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "main_resource_group" {
  name     = var.resource_group_name
  location = var.resource_group_location
}
```

Setup virtual network:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "test_vnet" {
  name                = var.vnet_name
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = var.resource_group_location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
}
```

Setup subnets:

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "private_snet" {
  name                 = "subnet-private"
  resource_group_name  = var.resource_group_name
  virtual_network_name = var.vnet_name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]

  delegation {
    name = "databricksprivatermdelegation"

    service_delegation {
      name = "Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces"
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "public_snet" {
  name                 = "subnet-public"
  resource_group_name  = var.resource_group_name
  virtual_network_name = var.vnet_name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]

  delegation {
    name = "databrickspublicdelegation"

    service_delegation {
      name = "Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces"
    }
  }
}
```

Setup firewals:

```
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "private_empty_nsg" {
  name                = "firewall-private"
  location            = var.resource_group_location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "private_nsg_asso" {
  subnet_id                 = azurerm_subnet.private_snet.id
  network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.private_empty_nsg.id
}

resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "public_empty_nsg" {
  name                = "firewall-public"
  location            = var.resource_group_location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "public_nsg_asso" {
  subnet_id                 = azurerm_subnet.public_snet.id
  network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.public_empty_nsg.id
}
```

And finally setup the databricks:

```
resource "azurerm_databricks_workspace" "forex_price_databricks" {
  name                = "databricks-test"
  location            = var.resource_group_location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  sku                 = "standard"
  custom_parameters {
    virtual_network_id                                  = azurerm_virtual_network.test_vnet.id
    public_subnet_name                                  = azurerm_subnet.public_snet.name
    public_subnet_network_security_group_association_id = azurerm_network_security_group.public_empty_nsg.id
    private_subnet_name                                 = azurerm_subnet.private_snet.name
    private_subnet_network_security_group_association_id = azurerm_network_security_group.private_empty_nsg.id
  }
}
```

However, when i run the code in the first try i got the below error:

```
Error: Code="ResourceNotFound" Message="The Resource 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/my-vnet' under resource group 'My-Resource-Group' was not found.
```

So, the question is:

Why the Virtual Network is not created ? or cannot be found ?

---

**Update:**

When i remove the

```
  resource_group {
          prevent_deletion_if_contains_resources = false
        }
```

I used to have this line, becuse i usually run the `terraform destroy` and i don't want t remove my `resource group`. However, even if i remove it ,I got the below error:

Message="Operation was canceled." Details=[{"code":"
CanceledAndSupersededDueToAnotherOperation","message":"Operation PutVirtualNetworkOperation  was canceled and superseded by operation PutSubnetOpe
ration

Are you able to reproduce the same error ?

Comment: Check the Azure Portal. Does the resource exist? Is all this done in the same module or have you split it into multiple modules? If it's t he same, consider referencing the VNet directory instead of using the input variable. You're doing it in a few places with the subnet and security group.

Comment: What version of TF and AzureRM are you using? This has been a [bug](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/2754) on an older version.

Comment: `Terraform v1.2.5` but i don't know how to get AzureRM version !

Comment: Try referencing the resources instead of the input variable name. I'm guessing since there's no implicit dependency between the vnet and subnet it's not finished with the vnet when it starts to create the subnet. So either declare a `depends_on` or use `azurerm_virtual_network.test_vnet` in the subnet

Comment: And of course the same goes everywhere else you're using the input variable instead of the object reference.

Comment: The databrick is a child module in my local machine, so i have to pass some inputs as variables. I mean, i cannot directly reference to the object.

Comment: Then which object is giving the error? Since your databrick is using direct referencing, I assumed the error came from the subnet or something similair.